# Proving power series is uniformly continuous on given interval

Tags: real-analysis

Let $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (nx)}{1+n^3}$$

Prove that $f$ is continuous on $(-\infty,\infty)$.

My solution: We first note that $f$ converges uniformly on $(-\infty,\infty)$ since $$\left|\frac{\sin (nx)}{1+n^3}\right|\leq \frac{1}{n^3}$$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}<\infty$$ by p-test, then by W-M test $f(x)$ converges uniformly on $(-\infty,\infty)$. It then follows that $f$ is continuous $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Let me know if I made any mistakes in doing this proof. My question is: Can we conclude that f is uniformly continuous too?If not why? Any suggestions, hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Btw, that's not a power series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have for any $\epsilon>0$,

$$\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(y)|&=\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)-\sin(ny)}{1+n^3}\right| \tag 1\\\\
&\le 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left|\sin\left(\frac{n(x-y)}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{n(x+y)}{2}\right)\right|}{1+n^3} \tag 2\\\\
&\le |x-y|\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{1+n^3} \tag 3\\\\
&\le \frac{\pi^2}{6}|x-y| \tag 4\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $0<|x-y|<\delta = \frac{6}{\pi^2}\epsilon$.  And we are done!  $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

**NOTES:**

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we used the [Prosthaphaeresis Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#Reverse_identities) for the difference $\sin(a)-\sin(b)$.

In going from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we used the inequality $|\sin(\theta)|\le |\theta|$.

In going from $(3)$ to $(4)$ , we used the inequality $1+n^3\ge n^3$ along with the solution to the [Basel Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\pi^2/6$.

Comment: Here's another way to estimate the difference of sines: By the mean value theorem, $\sin(ny) - \sin(nx) = \cos (c)(ny-nx),$ for some $c$ between $nx$ and $ny.$ Thus $|\sin(ny) - \sin(nx)| \le n|y-x|.$

Comment: @zhw Yes, that works equally well.